# Change port number used by .NET WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

How can I change the port number used by WebBrowser control? The standard port number is 80, but I would like to use a different port.

Comment: Can you provide more information? It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do and how it relates to .NET.

Comment: I'm trying to change the port number because port 81 is blocked by another program.

Comment: Are you trying to reach a URL with :81 in it? If that port is blocked, then it's blocked.

Answer (score 8):

You should specify an alternate port number in the URL itself:

```
http://server:port/path?query
```

Answer (score 4):

The web browser control is a client.  To connect to the server on different port, you change the URL.

```
ex: http://www.mysite.com:81/
```

would attempt to connect to the site on port 81.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about the [System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) class?

If so, then set the Url property using the format Mehrdad mentioned, or go there using the Navigate() method:

```
http://server:port/path?query
```

Example:

```
WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser();
w.Navigate(new Uri("http://server:port/path?query"));
```

Comment: "Are you asking about the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser class?" - Yes

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to change the local port of the web browser, I'm not sure that you can.  The Windows API automatically assigns a local port to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOS command "netstat -anb"  to find out what process is holding port 81 on your machine.